# header('Content-type: image/png'); makes the browser all black

Tags: php, header

This a script from PHP.net

```
// Create the image handle, set the background to white
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 100, 100, imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255));    
// Draw an ellipse to fill with a black border
imageellipse($im, 50, 50, 50, 50, imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0));
// Set the border and fill colors
$border = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$fill = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0);
// Fill the selection
imagefilltoborder($im, 50, 50, $border, $fill);
// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

The line HEADER make the browser all black!
Why? Whats wrong?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot please ?

Comment: That is not what i have. Simply copy paste you script; with GD activated produce a red ball. Try removing header('Content-type: image/png'); for debugging purpose.

Comment: I can´t add an image as I don´t have enough reputation :(

Comment: It would seem that the php library to handle image GD is not installed type phpinfo(); and see if this is correct

Comment: I have typed phpinfo, now what do I look for?

Comment: GD Version  bundled (2.0.34 compatible)

Comment: works well for me, check your gd version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

Forces your browser to interpret your output as an image of type png.

Even though your code is fine and does not produce an error. It's very likely that you are missing GD or your environment is badly configured and do return an error.
But because of the `header`, the error output is behing interpreted as an image.

Try removing it and ensure that the displayed string is a correct raw png data.

Edit:
After debugging with OP, it came out that his script had a whitespace character before declaring open php tags `<?php`.
This small thing was sent as well with the correct png data and messed up the whole data for the browser interpreting it.

Comment: When I remove the line , it will give me text garbage like this"‰PNG  IHDR,,ö" IDATxœí½MÌÕ‘/^ýø5É¹aF±‰m,FB1ì8wP”UÈ‚\”l±Á6ƒˆ4€Á!ëåƒ Â—"

Comment: That seems to be a correct PNG data.
Can you comfirm that nothing have been append before and after the content ? (use view-source: to have the full raw content).
What is you environnement and browser ?

Comment: Yes there is nothing more than the image code. It is Firefox latest version in a Windows 7

Comment: No I only have a black browser

Comment: Does another browser have this issue ?

Comment: In Chrome it a totaly white page, in IE is garbage

Comment: Ok, so at least it's not a browser issue.
Also, your code do work for me. So ... was this only an extract of your code of the full script ?

Comment: Copy and paste from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilltoborder.php

Comment: I'm slowly reaching a deadend, last chance.
Remove header function. Use chrome and access the page.
Open developper console (Ctrl+Maj+I).
Execute `btoa(encodeURIComponent(escape(document.body.innerHTML)))`.
Give me the output from console.

Comment: Does it end with `dTAxN0QlMjUyNmd0JTI1M0JJRU5EJTI1QUVCJTI1NjAlMjV1MjAxQQ==` ?

Comment: Ok, we have the same beginning but different ending. I still does not know what is messing up but your data is altered. Could you copy your full output here ? http://pastebin.com/

Comment: OKAYYYYY, your output had a very very tiny micro error that messed up the whole image.
For a reason a space was output BEFORE the output of the image.
Check your script and remove any space or linebreak that is before <?php

Comment: It is working now! Wooow you are great! Thanks Why don´t you put your answer as an Answer, so I can mark it as Accepted? Thanks again :)

Comment: I will edit my answer. Hope you saw how we slowly eliminate possibility and search. That one was tricky ;)